# failing JSON data validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am failing a JSON data validation test, where I am supposed to create a JSON object **persons** with with properties Name, EmployeeID, Experience, Company and Designation and access it using loop.
I am just learning JSON and I think the problem is that it requires knowledge of nodejs too
here is the json file (data.json)

```
'{"Name":"someName","EmployeeID":123,"Experience":123,"Company":"somecompany","Designation":"someDesignation"}'
```

Here is the js file:

```
let jsonData = require('./data.json');
let persons=JSON.parse('./data.json', jsonData);
for(i in persons){
    console.log(persons.i);
}
```

and here is the validation file:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const fss =require('fs');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    Name: Joi.string().required(),
    EmployeeID: Joi.number().required(),
    Experience: Joi.number().required(),
    Company: Joi.string().required(),
    Designation: Joi.string().required()
});

const personSchema=Joi.object().keys({
  persons:schema.required()
}).required();

var data;

try{
 data = require("./data.json");    
}catch(e)
{
 data={};
}

var XMLWriter = require('xml-writer');
    xw = new XMLWriter;




// You can also pass a callback which will be called synchronously with the validation result.
Joi.validate(data, personSchema, function (err, value) {
if(err==null)
{   
  console.log("JSON data is valid, Status: Passed");
}else{
    console.log("JSON data is invalid. Status: failed")
}

});
```

I am getting **JSON data is invalid. Status: failed**

Comment: Lose the surrounding `'`

Comment: Employee ID with a space?

Comment: absolutely not brother @taygetos , this I wrong typed here

Comment: No @Utkanos , I tried this way with other hands-on, this is not the actual problem

Comment: If, as you say, your JSON lives in and is being loaded form its own file, then the wrapping `'` will absolutely be a problem. It may not be your *only* problem, however.

Comment: From your example your EmployeeId and Experience are strings but you are validating for numbers.

Comment: may be @Utkanos but I tried it as you said but still it is not working

Comment: yeah that might be a problem but now tried it with EmployeeID and Experience as number but still not working @worker11811

Comment: `let jsonData = require('./data.json');
let persons=JSON.parse('./data.json', jsonData);` you're using it wrong. JSON.parse first argument is the JSON string and the second argument is an optional function, not an object ... but `require` a JSON file results in an object from the parsed JSON, so you don't need to parse it - see answer for how you shouldbe doing it

Comment: you might be correct @Bravo I will try what you said but we should not edit the **verify.js** file if want to pass a hands-on fairly, btw verify.js is editable but what if it is **Read only**

Comment: if verify is "read only" then clearly the object required in the `.json` file is different to what you have, and to what I thought it needs to be - I'll add something to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of what you need to create, it seems you need an Array of those objects

So, the JSON should be

```
[{"Name":"someName","EmployeeID":123,"Experience":123,"Company":"somecompany","Designation":"someDesignation"}]
```

Then the "JS" would be

```
let persons=require('./data.json');
for(let i in persons){
    console.log(persons[i]);
}
```

And the validator would be

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const fss = require('fs');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        Name: Joi.string().required(),
        EmployeeID: Joi.number().required(),
        Experience: Joi.number().required(),
        Company: Joi.string().required(),
        Designation: Joi.string().required()
    });

const personSchema = Joi.array().items(schema.required()).required();

var data;

try {
    data = require("./data.json");
} catch (e) {
    data = [];
}

var XMLWriter = require('xml-writer');
xw = new XMLWriter;

// You can also pass a callback which will be called synchronously with the validation result.
Joi.validate(data, personSchema, function (err, value) {
    if (err == null) {
        console.log("JSON data is valid, Status: Passed");
    } else {
        console.log(err, "JSON data is invalid. Status: failed")
    }

});
```

---

> if the validator file should be left untouched, then the JSON needs to be as follows

```
{"persons":{"Name":"someName","EmployeeID":123,"Experience":123,"Company":"somecompany","Designation":"someDesignation"}}
```

Comment: Here is the error @Bravo
```
  [ { message: '"value" does not contain 1 required value(s)',
       path: [],
       type: 'array.includesRequiredUnknowns',
       context: [Object] } ],
  _object: [],
  annotate: [Function] } 'JSON data is invalid. Status: failed'
```
btw I wanna pass this hands-on by fair means only so if there is something that you can suggest except verify.js then thanks in advance

Comment: there is no error - this passes @Krishnakant ... and ``` is not an error, it's a bunch of backticks

Comment: yes this time your JSON is correct, but one thing still I don't get that when I tried your JSON as you wrote it didn't worked but when i tried it as **"{\"persons\":{\"Name\":\"someName\",\"EmployeeID\":123,\"Experience\":123,\"Company\":\"somecompany\",\"Designation\":\"someDesignation\"}}"** it worked, what is difference between these two data

Comment: huh? you need \ in the .json file?